# Laravel redirect to intended keeps sending my users to json requests http get

Tags: laravel

Sometimes, a user session expires, no matter the reason. The user is redirected to the login page, as my routes sends the user there in case of `Auth::guest()`.

Then it sends them back after successful login to an ajax/json page (like a list of images in json) - this happens because I'm using the `Redirect::intended()` call. This is completely unusable then - how do people work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Using `Redirect::guest()` saves the requested URL to the session key `url.intended`. If you use `Redirect::guest()` in a filter on an AJAX route, this will still be the case and the URL of that AJAX call will be where the user is sent.

You can use `if(Request::ajax()) {}` to do something different for AJAX responses, like returning an error JSON instead of a redirect.